# form upload get other form variables in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I have an asp.net form upload box that I copied from MSDN.
After the form is submitted, instead of displaying the information on the page, I want the page to redirect with 2 query parameters, the filename and a number which was a hidden form field, in the same form and the upload box.
How can I get that number after the form submits to add to the redirect code.
My form field name is 'id'

```
<script runat="server">
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("C:\inetpub\sites\rebbetzin\uploads\" & _
               FileUpload1.FileName)
            Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName & "<br>" & _
               "File Size: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength & " kb<br>" & _
               "Content type: " & _
               FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType

                Response.Redirect("http://www.rebbetzins.org/thanks.asp?id=" &  ______ & "&f=" & FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName )
        Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value is stored in the `Request.Form` collection, like this:

```
Request.Form("id")
```

So your `Response.Redirect` code should look like this:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.rebbetzins.org/thanks.aspx?id=" & Request.Form("id") & "&f=" & FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName )
```

Note: The `thanks` page is an `.aspx` and not an `.asp` extension, right? I changed it to `.aspx` in my answer.

UPDATE:

Since you have an ASP.NET server control holding the hidden value, then you can just do this instead:

```
Me.id2.Value
```

So your `Response.Redirect` will now look like this:

```
Response.Redirect("http://www.rebbetzins.org/thanks.aspx?id=" & Me.id2.Value & "&f=" & FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName )
```

UPDATE 2:

To populate the ASP.NET HiddenField control in the `thanks.aspx` page, you need to read it out of the query string in the `Page_Load` event, like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Request.QueryString("id") IsNot Nothing Then
        Me.id2.Value = Request.QueryString("id")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: How do I get that query parameter into my form field?
    <asp:HiddenField ID="id2" runat="server"   />

Comment: Just use the `Value` property of the hidden field control. See `UPDATE:` in my answer.

Comment: I need the opposite. I have on the thanks.aspx page the same hidden field called id2. I want that id from the url to populate into that field.

Comment: See `UPDATE 2:` in my answer for how to get the value of the query string and put it in the hidden field on the `thanks.aspx` page.

Answer (score 0):

request.form("id") should contain the value in that hidden form field.